# get the miniumum value in pandas vectorization

Tags: python, pandas

I'm creating a column which is based on 2 other columns but also has an extra condition:

`df['C'] = min((df['B'] - df['A']) , 0)`

The new column is the subtraction of A and B, but if the value is negative it has to be 0. The above function does not work unfortunately. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`df.clip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html) to set a lower bound for the data (i.e. any data below 0 to show as 0):

```
df['C'] = (df['B'] - df['A']).clip(lower=0)
```

Note: If you don't want any negatives, your original idea should use max rather than min. A negative would be < 0, it would keep the negative. You'd end up replacing all positive numbers with 0 rather than the negatives (e.g. `min(-5, 0)` would output -5)

Comment: thanks, and you're right. sloppy mistake

Comment: @borisvanax if this helped it would be good if you could accept it :)